# Instantiate class using dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

Im trying to use a HTML view to [string rendering class i found online](https://gist.github.com/ahmad-moussawi/1643d703c11699a6a4046e57247b4d09). Its called PDFRender atm cause this is what it will be used for. Ive been told that its set up using Dependency Injection and that it should work out of the box.

Im not sure how to instantiate it though. Since the dependencies are supposed to be injected through the constructor.

My class constructor look like this

```
      public PdfRender(IRazorViewEngine viewEngine, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _viewEngine = viewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

    }
```

And i set it up in the Startup classes ConfigureMetod() like this

```
     // Set up Report PDF html renderer 
        services.AddScoped<PdfRender, PdfRender>();
```

Now m trying this in my code (after looking at the links example)

```
            PdfRender pdfRender;
        string iWantToBetml = pdfRender.ModelToHTML(inspection);
```

But i get an error (ofcourse) saying that i cant use an unassigned variable. I guess i dont understand how the DI is supposed to be used. Im assuming the idea is to give the default viewEngine, dataProvider and serviceProviders.

Comment: All DI dependencies need to be defined in StarUp itself something like services.AddScoped<IRazorViewEngine, RazorViewEngine>(). Alternatively you can write an extension method on IServiceCollection and call the same in StarUp.

Comment: "But i get an error (ofcourse) saying that i cant use an unassigned variable.". Your example is incomplete. Please post all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a `PdfRender` parameter to the constructor of your controller:

```
  public PdfRender(PdfRender pdfRender, IRazorViewEngine viewEngine, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
    _pdfRender = pdfRender;
    _viewEngine = viewEngine;
    _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
```

Then you can use in in an instance method on that controller

```
  public SomeMethod(){
      string iWantToBetml = _pdfRender.ModelToHTML(inspection);
  }
```

Note that in your controller constructor you don't necessarily need to specify all these parameters, just specify the ones that the class needs and then those will be injected in from the DI container provided their types have been registered with the DI container at startup.